# Instalación de extensiones en visual 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Como puedo instalar las extensiones Microsoft Report Service Project y Microsoft RDLC Report Designer?

> Necesito instalar esas extensiones pero en el visual que tengo (2015)no me aparecen y las descargo en linea y me marca error

Comment: que error? a que te referis con no me aparecen? por favor mira [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAludos te comento que al menos la primera extensión requiere visual studio 2017 o superior por lo cual deberías considerar actualizarlo

Te actualizo de a cuerdo al market place de Microsoft ambas funcionan pero con la versión 2017